# Returning a different provider (binding) based on an object (callcontext) with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm trying to return a different provider, depending on a custom context. Given the following

```
public interface IProvider
{
    string WhoAreYou();
}
```

And two providers

```
namespace ProviderOne
{
    public class Implementation : IProvider
    {
        public string WhoAreYou()
        {
            return "Provider One";
        }
    }
}

namespace ProviderTwo
{
    public class Implementation : IProvider
    {
        public string WhoAreYou()
        {
            return "Provider Two";
        }
    }
}
```

And a context as follows

```
public class CallContext
{
    public string SomeValue{ get; set; }
    public int AnotherValue { get; set; }
}
```

My binding looks like this

```
        CallContext context1 = new CallContext()
        {
            SomeValue = "one",
            AnotherValue = 1
        };

        Bind<IProvider>().To<ProviderOne.Implementation>().WithMetadata("callcontext", context1);

        CallContext context2 = new CallContext()
        {
            SomeValue = "two",
            AnotherValue = 2
        };

        Bind<IProvider>().To<ProviderOne.Implementation>().WithMetadata("callcontext", context2);
```

I'm fairly certain it is correct up to here, though it's late, and I'm out of ideas.

My problem is getting to those bindings. I have tried various methods

```
        var test1 = kernel.Get<IProvider>(b => b.Get<CallContext>("callcontext") == context1);
        //var test1 = kernel.Get<IProvider>(m => m.Has("callcontext") && m.Get<CallContext>("callcontext").Equals(context1));
        //var test1 = kernel.Get<IProvider>(m => m.Get<CallContext>("callcontext").Equals(context1));
        //var test1 = kernel.Get<IProvider>().Equals(context1);
```

But they don't work, at best I get the "No binding" error, at worst I just get errors. I'm sure there must be something easy I am overlooking, or just no aware off.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, and if anyone runs up against this in the future, the solution above is fine, except you have to explicit override Equals for Ninject to resolve to the object. As follows.

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(CallContext))
        {
            var context = (CallContext)obj;

            if (Country != null)
            {
                if (Country.ToLower() != context.Country.ToLower())
                    return false;
            }


            if (Store != context.Store)
                return false;


            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Then you can resolve it as proposed.

```
    CallContext context1 = new CallContext()
    {
        SomeValue = "one",
        AnotherValue = 1
    };

    var test1 = kernel.Get<IProvider>(b => b.Get<CallContext>("callcontext").Equals(context1));
```